# Problems with a table in a div box that doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am building this quiz page and I have to include a scoreboard.

The problem with my scoreboard is that I am trying to put it in a table. When the table gets bigger than 4 rows (which it eventually will), it just keeps on going.

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

I tried using overflow: auto / overflow: scroll / overflow-y: auto

but it doesn't force a scrollbar. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to post that code in a fiddle for us?

Comment: you have to add height as some specific pixel with overflow property.

Comment: @Mike - It's kinda hard since the whole code is built around certain files and php dependencies that are in other files.

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions - The box itself has a height property. Is it a problem that it's in %? does it have to be in pixels?

Comment: Yes please change the height to pixel and overflow-y: auto

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions Thank you very much! That fixed it when I switched to pixels instead of %. If you could post it as an answer I would mark it :)

Comment: Yes I added and thanks for the appreciation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add height to the section in pixel and overflow-y as auto. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you could move the table a bit upper or make the div container longer. what about to increase the height of the background image?